Problems with rjtools to create an article for submission to the RJournal
I am trying to prepare an article for submission to the Rjournal using the method they propose, but I keep getting error messages even trying to render the document test.Rmd included in rjtools. I have had these problems before, and eventually gave up, submitting an old style latex file to the RJournal. But this time I really would like to find out how to do it properly.
So first I updated all the programs/packages involved, as far as I know what they are.
Then I create a new folder tmp and run rjtools::create_article()
Next I run run rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")
and this yields:   Error: CCTZ: Unrecognized output timezone: "Etc/GMT+4"
Now this one I know, there is an issue with the date format. Changing to
date: October 11, 2024
in test.Rmd fixes it. It just seems strange that after several years this bug is still there.
And again run rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")
This time I get
Error:
! in callr subprocess.
Caused by error:
! LaTeX failed to compile RJwrapper.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See RJwrapper.log for more info.
? See $stdout and $stderr for standard output and error.
Type .Last.error to see the more details.
Looking at RJwrapper.txt I see
! Undefined control sequence.
l.72 \pandocbounded
{\includegraphics[keepaspectratio]{test_files/figure-late...
So this seems to have to do some figures. But I don't care about those anyway,
so I now delete everything in test.Rmd except the line
The \CRANpkg{palmerpenguins} data [@palmerpenguins]
after the Introduction section header
And again run rmarkdown::render("test.Rmd")
again I get the same error as last time, but now RJwrapper.text has
! LaTeX Error: Lonely \item--perhaps a missing list environment.
Searching the internet I found many mention of this error, although
many unconnected to rjtools. The error seems to arise from the bibliography, and
in fact when I remove the [@palmerpenguins]  from test.Rmd the compiles now without errors.
I found several propose solutions on the internet:
https://github.com/rjournal/rjtools/issues/117 said this was an issue of pandoc versions, and suggested to run
pandoc::with_pandoc_version(version = '3.1.6.2',
rmarkdown::render('test.Rmd'))
but this didn't work for me
https://github.com/rjournal/rjtools/issues/124 suggests to also edit the output section of test.Rmd, but again no luck.
https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/387937/bibentry-with-template-causes-error-lonely-item-perhaps-a-missing-list-enviro
says that it is a clash between the hyperref and bibentry packages and suggests to add
\usepackage{bibentry}
\makeatletter\let\saved@bibitem@bibitem\makeatother
\usepackage{hyperref}
\makeatletter\let@bibitem\saved@bibitem\makeatother
in RJwrapper.tex, but again no luck.
The page https://github.com/rjournal/rjtools/issues/119 has a discussion of several other issues when trying to use rjtools.
So I am wondering what else I could try?
Wolfgang
